# Trying to implement last_login_timestamp in User entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to implement a last login timestamp in database for the entity "User". When I do the login and I generate the token, I want to update the "last_login_timestamp" to LocalDateTime.now() and then save it to database. Here is my method from my session controller:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequestData loginData) throws QOException {
    User usuario;

    try {
        usuario = userService.getByEmail(loginData.getUsername());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new InvalidCredentialsException("El usuario no está asociado a la bbdd");
    }


    if (BCrypt.checkpw(loginData.getPassword(),usuario.getPassword())) {

        SessionData datosSession = new SessionData(usuario.getEmail(),
                usuario.getName() + " " + usuario.getSurname());

        final String token = tokenHelper.generate(datosSession);

        LoginResponse resultado = new LoginResponse(token, usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getName() + " " + usuario.getSurname());

        usuario.setLast_login_timestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        userService.update(usuario);

        return resultado;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidCredentialsException("Contraseña no válida");
    }

}
```

When I login, the timestamp is updated correctly BUT I don't know why, the update query is also including the password (and I don't give it any value, I only get it from the user entity) and it changes it to whatever. Here is the query generated by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 

update
    database.user 
set
    modification_date=?,
    _version=?,
    last_login_timestamp=?,
    password=? 
where
    id=? 
    and _version=?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't the update query always include all properties? when you say that it changes the password to "whatever" - then does it actually change the password to a different value or does it remain the same?

Comment: What happens inside `userService.update(usuario);` ? How are you interacting with Hibernate? Are you using Spring Data as well?

Comment: @msparer true, it includes all the properties and it's saving the encrypted password so it encrypts it again lol

Comment: @WimDeblauwe in the service I encrypt the password and then set it through setPassword. I think I'm going to make a method to just only save the last_login_timestamp

Comment: @Jessie sounds like you should rather encrypt it outside of the `User` context. Sounds like asking for trouble if data changes when you save an unmodified object.